# Handling files over maxFilesize in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I'm working on a blog/gallery in Symfony 2 and have followed the Doctrine File Uploads section of the Symfony 2 book almost verbatum. The file uploads work fine usually, but if the file is over a certain size (I think whatever UploadedFile::getMaxFilesize() is) then a FileNotFound exception is thrown when a new UploadedFile() is created because while the request contains a reference to that file it doesn't contain the file itself.

I'm assuming this needs to be handled during form validation, but I'm having trouble finding much info online about how to go about it. Any pointers to the best course of action would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Take care to set the upload_max_filesize param in your php.ini to a higher value than the value in your

```
/**
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
 */
```

annotation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can find all needed info in the cookbook at [How to handle File Uploads with Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) page.

Notice the annotation:

```php
/**
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
 */
```

Comment: After a bit more reading it seems the problem is not so simple. If the file is over the upload_max_filesize value in php.ini (which UploadedFile::getMaxFilesize() returns) then the request doesn't contain the file contents and the filesize is passed to Symfony as zero... so the maxSize annotation validation will always pass if the uploaded file is larger than upload_max_filesize. For now I've added some code to the controller to throw a FileException if the filesize is zero, but I think a better solution would be to create a custom validator which checks the filesize is greater than zero.

Comment: The UploadedFile class has some handy methods for dealing with this. UploadedFile::isValid() will tell you if the upload was successful, and UploadedFile::getError() will return the PHP file upload error number if there was an error. The error codes are explained here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Answer (score 1):

Symfony sets maxSize also in this file :

```
src/AppBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
```

or in old versions :

```
src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
```

be sure to change it too.